# Why dropdownlist values not binding into database

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular JS MVC here data is binding into dropdownlist but when I try to load the value into database but that data not binfing:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="margin-left:20px">
                                <b>State</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                                  <select class="form-control" data-modal="modal" ng-options="I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountryList" ng-model="CountryID" ng-change="StateList()" ng-required="true">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>--Select Country--</option>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**angular code**

```
$scope.AddUpdateEmployee = function (Emp) {
        alert("Enter in update")
        var Employee = {
            Id: $scope.EmployeeId,
            Name: $scope.EmployeeName,
            Email: $scope.EmployeeEmail,
            Psw: $scope.Password,
            Country: $scope.CountryID,

        };
```

**mvc code**

```
   public JsonResult AddEmployee( Employee emps)
        {
            if (emps != null)
            {
                Employee ee = new Employee();
                ee.Name = emps.Name;
                ee.Email = emps.Email;
                ee.Psw = emps.Psw;
                ee.Country = emps.Country;
                ee.State = emps.State;
                ee.City = emps.City;
            }
```

Comment: Do you when you try to post data to database? Can i see the whole code, right now you are sharing just an piece, i need to see html where you are binding Employee?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below, its binding from the database.

http://jsfiddle.net/81t6cbjw/261/

```
  <select class="form-control" data-modal="modal" 
           ng-options="I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountryList" 
           ng-model="CountryID" ng-change="StateList()" ng-required="true">
       <option value="" disabled selected>--Select Country--</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ng-if` in select element, the problem element render before the data is coming, `ng-if` sets a watch on it

```
<select ng-if="CountryList && CountryList.length" class="form-control" data-modal="modal" ng-options="I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountryList" ng-model="CountryID" ng-change="StateList()" ng-required="true">
       <option value="" disabled selected>--Select Country--</option>
</select>
```